# efficient way to compare datetime

Tags: c#

Am trying to execute the formula like below,just wondering what's the efficient method to do,

Below is the formula to calculate

**result=  min(max(dtmealstart1,dtbkgstart),dtbkgend)**

```
dtmealstart1= 11/02/13 8AM
dtbkgstart=11/02/13 9AM
dtbkgend=11/02/13 17.00 (5PM)
result=min(max(11/02/13 8AM,11/02/13 9AM),11/02/13 17.00 )
result=11/02/13 9AM
```

I just wrote this piece of code in c# to do the above logic but am just wondering is there any best way to do

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(dtmealStart1, dtBkgStart);
DateTime break1;
if (result < 0)
{
    break1 = dtBkgStart;
}
else
{
    break1 = dtmealStart1;
}
int result1 = DateTime.Compare(break1, dtBkgEnd);
DateTime mealstart1;
if(result1<0)
{
    mealstart1 = break1;
}
else
{
    mealstart1 = dtBkgEnd;
}
```

my `mealstart1` value also bring it back `11/02/13 9AM`

Comment: I don't think you can get much better than the solution you've posted.

Comment: `DateTime` is flawed by design. Use NodaTime

Comment: @Habib, one is "result" another one is "result1"

Comment: Did you profile your code and obtain that this piece of code is your bottleneck? Is it a part of very hot loop? Why do you want to optimize this part of code?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, just my curiousity nothing wrong with that piece of code but always trying to find the best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Math` class on the `DateTime` Ticks

Something like:

```
 DateTime result = new DateTime(Math.Min(Math.Max(dtmealStart1.Ticks, dtBkgStart.Ticks), dtBkgEnd.Ticks));

 // result = 11/02/13 9AM
```

Comment: i haven't tested this but just wanna know the other option to write the logic.

Comment: Should that be DateTime rather than DatTime? (Not a C# programmer!)

Comment: @halfer, well I cant change it now, it would be to obvious, LOL :)